# Detached views in eclipse on linux

Tags: eclipse

When i detach wiews in eclipse on ubuntu, eg package explorer, it shows up as a separate window in ubuntu (Eclipse ends up taking up 4 windows, and that makes alt-tabbing through my open programs a pain)

Is there a way to fix this so Eclipse only show up as one window in ubuntu no matter how many vews are detached?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse probably opens the views was windows, not as dialogs. You can check this: Try to move one of the views behind the main Eclipse window. If you can do this, it's not a dialog (or the dialog wasn't initialized right ...)

In this case, using non-modal dialogs might be better.

I'd file a bug against Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: It's not possible to move the window behind the main window, so it must be something else. 
I tried starting gimp (the first other multi-view app that came to mind) and it behaves nice (as i was expecting eclipse).

Comment: This seems to be a problem when eclipse is restoring the workbench.
The multi-window-problem only occurs after startup. If i close the packageExplorer and then opens it again, it behaves like a proper dialoge of eclipse, not showing up in taskbar. closing and reopening views as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Actually found this in the [Eclipse bugzilla.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=227139)

A workaround is to close and reopen detached views when restarting the workbench